azure-aws-login TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load')
I have updated Node.js via nvm and reinstalled aws-azure-login and reconfigured it, but the issue still persists. What could be the problem and how can I resolve it?
npm update -g aws-azure-login  
npm  -g aws-azure-login  

How do I Fix it?

aws-azure-login -f --profile awsgs-iam-organization --no-prompt
Logging in with profile 'awsgs-iam-organization'...
Using AWS SAML endpoint https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml
? Password: [hidden]
Open your Authenticator app, and enter the number shown to sign in.
31TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load')
at Object._parseRolesFromSamlResponse (/Users/thanaporn-s/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/lib/login.js:663:40)at Object.loginAsync (/Users/thanaporn-s/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/lib/login.js:379:28

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This helped me.
https://github.com/aws-azure-login/aws-azure-login/issues/339#issuecomment-2290950342
Please note if you are using nvm global node_modules location will be below on MAC
/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v20.16.0/lib/node_modules

